# Azure Table storage insert speed jumps from very fast to very slow

Tags: performance, azure, azure-table-storage

We are inserting large amount of data into Azure Table storage, and while usually it goes quite fast (up to 20K rows per minute), sometimes insert speed drops by 20-25 times, down to 800-1000 rows per minute. When this happens, to bring up the speed I just stop and restart the applications, and then insert is fast again. Same application, same computer, everything is the same - just a new session.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? How can this be explained?

Comment: Sounds like you're getting throttled.  Can you batch the inserts?

Comment: Currently I am using Parallel.ForEach with up to 50 parallel inserts. I can try creating batches, thanks for the tip.